# Printing Tiled Background images in IE/Chrome

Tags: html, css, printing

I have kind of a swoosh on my web page and I am using a tiled image to make the vertical and horizontal lines that go down and across the page. The page looks fine when it is displayed in the browser, however, when printing the vertical and horizontal line image is not tiled leaving a blank gap on the page. Below is the code that I am using to create the left hand portion of the swoosh..

```
        <td style="width:100%;" colspan="2">
        <table border=0 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:170px;"><img src="CurveBottom.png" /></td>
                <td style="width:530px;background-image:url('HorizontalLine.png');">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    </td>
```

Comment: Tables for layout that use background images? Is this actually 2012? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296326

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion? Is there a better way to be doing this?